# Chef spec tests with not_if guard

Tags: chef-recipe, recipe

I have the following chef resoutce

```
  rpm_package 'Install BESAgent' do
    source node['besclient']['package_url']
    action :install
    not_if { "rpm -qa | grep -qx 'BESAgent-9.5.9.62-rhe6.x86_64'" || "rpm -qa | grep -qx 'BESAgent-9.5.9.62-sle11.x86_64'" }
  end
```

Corresponding to this I Have the following chef spec test

```
it 'installs rpm_package for BES Client' do
  expect(chef_run).to install_rpm_package('Install BESAgent').with(source: 'http://software.bigfix.com/download/bes/95/BESAgent-9.5.9.62-rhe6.x86_64.rpm' , not_if: '{ \"rpm -qa | grep -qx \'BESAgent-9.5.9.62-rhe6.x86_64\'\" || \"rpm -qa | grep -qx \'BESAgent-9.5.9.62-sle11.x86_64\'\"}'))
end
```

which gives a warning

```
[2018-04-17T21:18:03+05:30] WARN: not_if block for rpm_package[Install BESAgent]
returned "rpm -qa | grep -qx 'BESAgent-9.5.9.62-rhe6.x86_64'", did you mean to
run a command? If so use 'not_if "rpm -qa | grep -qx 'BESAgent-9.5.9.62-rhe6.x86_64'"' in your code.
```

and the following error

```
  1) besclient::linux redhat 6.8: when all attributes are default installs rpm_
ackage for BES Client
     Failure/Error: expect(chef_run).to install_rpm_package('Install BESAgent')
with(source: 'http://software.bigfix.com/download/bes/95/BESAgent-9.5.9.62-rhe6
x86_64.rpm', not_if: '{ \"rpm -qa | grep -qx \'BESAgent-9.5.9.62-rhe6.x86_64\'\
 || \"rpm -qa | grep -qx \'BESAgent-9.5.9.62-sle11.x86_64\'\"}')
       expected "rpm_package[Install BESAgent]" actions [] to include :install
```

Comment: Instead of spawning a sub-shell you could look for a package in `node['packages']` Mash.

Answer (score 1):

When you use command inside [not_if](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html) block, you don't need to use curly braces. You can use simply use double or single quotes

```
not_if "rpm -qa | grep -qx 'BESAgent-9.5.9.62-rhe6.x86_64'" || "rpm -qa | grep -qx 'BESAgent-9.5.9.62-sle11.x86_64'"
```